# force browser zoom conditionally

Tags: javascript, html, css, resize, zooming

I need a div that is 768x900 px to be entire visible within the browser window. If the browser window is too small and/or too zoomed, part of the div is currently truncated.

What I want is something that effectively accomplishes the following:
-if the browser dimensions and/or zoom upon page load are such that this 768x900 px div would not entirely fit (i.e., be truncated), force the browser to go to a zoom level that fits the div in its entirety
-if the browser dimensions and/or zoom are such that the div would fit, don't need to do anything
-if resize browser window, recalculate the above

I know that %s would be one way to accomplish this, but that's not a good solution here for several reasons.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You most likely what a responsive design which generally can be done with media queries. 
I would read up on responsive design if you don't know what that is.

Here are some tutorials that might be able to help you and explain things further.

http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries

http://css-tricks.com/resolution-specific-stylesheets

Answer (score 0):

If you have a css applied in the DIV where position is set as relative, This could cause this issue. Make sure position is set as absolute and then set the width/height. It will certainly work.

Comment: but if the browser height in pixels < the height of the div, the truncation will occur.